# EJS and jquery not loading javascript reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ejs

This is driving me insane.

I have a node app with express.  It serves up a file called index.ejs.

All I wanna do is import a javascript file on this page (something like jquery).  But it won't pull it up, and I'm going nuts (as this should be simple).

On the server side I have this code in a file called app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();
var hostName = (process.env.VCAP_APP_HOST || 'localhost');
app.listen( process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT ||  8000);
app.use(express.static(__dirname +  '/public/javascript/'));


//Create the view
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('view options', { layout: false });
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.ejs', {
              item : "document.write('Hello World');"
    });
});
```

In the ejs file, I have this:

```
<html>
        <script>
        <%= item %>
    </script>

<a href="">Link</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery.js"></script>
</html>
```

I can see in the console that the script is not loaded (it shows an error).  But for the life of me I can't figure out why.

Comment: What error does it show? What does the HTML look like if you view the source?

Comment: GET http://localhost:8000/javascript/jquery.js 404 (Not Found), viewing the source pretty much shows you what you'd expect.  It shows my script divs and the lot.

Comment: and I just realized I bungled the title.  Gahh, it's too late at night for this.

Comment: I'm thinking it's because the client isn't getting that javascript page, and that's why it's 404ing.  But I've referenced scripts that way before.  Why would it be mad now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a static server to serve the other files you have under '/'. Currently your server is just responding to requests sent to '/' (and views).

Add this line to your express setup before `app.get`:

```
// DOCUMENT_ROOT should point to the directory that contains your javascript directory.
app.use(express.static(DOCUMENT_ROOT));
```

Comment: Are you sure you're pointing your static server at the right directory? Could you update the question with your current code and some directory structure information?

Comment: Your static file server is pointing to `__dirname +  '/public/javascript/'` and your HTML is expecting the server to be at `/` since it's requesting `/javascript/jquery.js`. Either change your HTML to point to `/jquery.js` or your static file server to `__dirname +  '/public/'`.

Comment: NICE!!!  That was it!  This was made more awesome as I'm minutes from hopping on a plane and losing internet for the rest of the night.  Thank you!!!

Comment: You're most welcome. Have a safe flight and sleep tight. Looks like you've earned it :-)

Answer (score 0):

When your client asks for `/javascript/jquery.js`, your server is going to be looking for `/public/javascript/javascript/jquery.js`, and I rather doubt it will find it. Setting `express.static()`'s pathname to `__dirname +  '/public'` should work, assuming that `jquery.js` is actually located in `your_app/public/javascript`.